# Aggregation using $group to get the first element (with condition)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Supposing I have the following:

```
  {'start': '2011-01-29',
  'target': 0.0,
  'cat': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  'state': 0},

  {'start': '2011-01-25',
  'target': 1.0,
  'cat': [0, 1, 0, 3, 0],
  'state': 0},

  {'start': '2011-01-29',
  'target': 1.0,
  'cat': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  'state': 0}
```

I need to Group this collection by state in order to get:

- The oldest `start` date
- The sum of `Target`
- The `cat` array where the oldest date are.

Using:

```
{ 
            "$group": {
              "_id": {  "state": "$state",
                     }, 
              "sum": { "$sum": "$target" },
              "start": { "$min": "$start" },
              "cat": {"$first": "$cat"}

            } 
      }
```

I can get:

- The oldest `start` date
- The sum of `Target`

However I can't get:

- The `cat` array where the oldest date are.

My desired output:

```
  {'start': '2011-01-25',
  'target': 2.0,
  'cat': [0, 1, 0, 3, 0],
  'state': 0},
```

Comment: It should be `cat` instead of `feat_static_cat`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I just fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by keeping both the fields inside single `$min` expression.

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": { "state": "$state" },
    "sum": { "$sum": "$target" },
    "cat": {
      "$min": {
        "start": "$start",
        "cat": "$cat"
      }
    }
  }
},
{ "$replaceRoot": {
  "newRoot": {
    "$mergeObjects": [
      "$$ROOT",
      { "start": "$cat.start", "cat": "$cat.cat" }
    ]
  }
}}
```